# Docker: Windows 10 - Environment doesn't seem to recognizing docker scripts

Tags: docker, windows-10

I am trying to learn a little more in docker but am having problems running commands that I am copying straight from the internet and youtube.

In this particular example I have pulled the postgres image from docker which is available straight from https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres with no problems but when I try to load an example such as:

```
docker run -p 5432:5432 -d \ 
    -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres \
    -e POSTGRES_USER=postgres \
    -e POSTGRES_DB=stripe-exmaple \
    -v pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data \
    postgres
```

I run into an error that outputs this in the terminal:

```
C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin\docker.exe: invalid reference format.
See 'C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin\docker.exe run --help'.
-e : The term '-e' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the 
name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:2 char:5
+     -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres \
+     ~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (-e:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

-e : The term '-e' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the 
name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:3 char:5
+     -e POSTGRES_USER=postgres \
+     ~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (-e:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

-e : The term '-e' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the 
name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:4 char:5
+     -e POSTGRES_DB=stripe-exmaple \
+     ~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (-e:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

-v : The term '-v' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the 
name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:5 char:5
+     -v pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data \
+     ~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (-v:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

postgres : The term 'postgres' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the 
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:6 char:5
+     postgres
+     ~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (postgres:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I seem to be able to run single line image commands such as the one below which deployed with no problems:

```
docker run --name postgres0 -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password -d -p 5432:5432 postgres:alpine
```

I have tried:
- running the terminal/powershell in admin mode
- I tried adding C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin\ to environmental variables
- running the terminal/powershell from C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin\ *wasn't sure if that would make a difference
- running but that made my knees hurt

I am guessing it is a small windows 10 user error but am completely stuck here and would appreciate a tip out of this cul-de-sac

Comment: your on windows. the \ character is a way to break a command into multiple lines on linux systems. try to pull those out and just have it all in a single line to see where you land to start. then maybe this if you want to clean up later. https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://superuser.com/questions/1222009/line-break-in-windows-command-prompt&ved=2ahUKEwjfn5vB3oHqAhWOTDABHWywDLwQjjgwCnoECAkQAQ&usg=AOvVaw2azlCsAHbT2Q_980mqHEgc

Comment: *Facepalm. That is it! Thank you Goofballtech!! Only spent 4 hours trying to figure this out :-O

Comment: copy and pasting commands is always dangerous. Paster beware! Glad you got it figured though. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

adding here so it can be closed if it got you fixed up.

your on windows. the \ character is a way to break a command into multiple lines on linux systems. try to pull those out and just have it all in a single line to see where you land to start. then maybe this if you want to clean up later. https://superuser.com/questions/1222009/line-break-in-windows-command-prompt

Comment: Much Appreciated! Thank you!